Is it Necessary to Have Both a Live Region AND Also Announce Button Dots on a Carousel for ADA
I currently have a carousel with a list of TrustPilot reviews for my company. I have added a live region for announcing when the slide changes, but NVDA also announces when the dots change to current "Slide 1 of num" etc. This seems redundant and like I really only need one of these options? Is that correct?
Here is my HTML
<div role="region" aria-roledescription="carousel" aria-label="TrustPilot Reviews"
    class="trustpilot-reviews__carousel js-trustpilot">
    <h5 id="trustpilot-reviews_heading">Our favorite reviews</h5>
    <ul data-slides="5" class="trustpilot-reviews__inner">
        <li class="trustpilot-reviews__card current" aria-current="true" aria-hidden="false"
            style="transform: translateX(0%);">
            <blockquote class="pull-quote">
                <div class="pull-quote__date">09/16/2024</div>
                <p class="pull-quote__copy">Past experience with a family member…</p>
                <div aria-label="5 star rating" class="pull-quote__rating">
                    <div class="stars"><span class="star"></span> <span class="star"></span> <span class="star"></span>
                        <span class="star"></span> <span class="star"></span></div>
                </div>
                <div class="pull-quote__cite"><span class="pull-quote__name">Member Name</span> <span
                        class="pull-quote__source">
                        <picture class="image"><img src="/-/media/project/myproject/logos/trustpilot-logo.svg" alt="Alt">
                        </picture>
                    </span></div>
            </blockquote>
        </li>
      ...more slides...
    </ul>
    <div role="group" aria-label="Slide controls" class="trustpilot-controls"><button role="button"
            aria-label="Previous TrustPilot Reviews">&lt;</button>
        <nav class="trustpilot-dots">
            <ul class="trustpilot-slidenav">
                <li><button data-slide="0" aria-label="Slide 0 of 5" role="button" class="tp-dots current"
                        aria-current="true"><span aria-hidden="true" class="sr-only">Go to Slide 0</span></button></li>
                <li><button data-slide="1" aria-label="Slide 1 of 5" role="button" class="tp-dots"
                        aria-current="false"><span aria-hidden="true" class="sr-only">Go to Slide 1</span></button></li>
                <li><button data-slide="2" aria-label="Slide 2 of 5" role="button" class="tp-dots"
                        aria-current="false"><span aria-hidden="true" class="sr-only">Go to Slide 2</span></button></li>
                <li><button data-slide="3" aria-label="Slide 3 of 5" role="button" class="tp-dots"
                        aria-current="false"><span aria-hidden="true" class="sr-only">Go to Slide 3</span></button></li>
                <li><button data-slide="4" aria-label="Slide 4 of 5" role="button" class="tp-dots"
                        aria-current="false"><span aria-hidden="true" class="sr-only">Go to Slide 4</span></button></li>
            </ul>
        </nav> <button role="button" aria-label="Next TrustPilot Reviews">&gt;</button>
    </div>
    <div aria-live="polite" aria-atomic="true" class="liveregion visuallyhidden"></div>
</div>

My VUE code for updating the liveregion on the fly (this gets called from my other methods to advance the slider):
announceSlides(n) {
  var liveregion = document.querySelector('.liveregion');
  liveregion.textContent = 'Item ' + n + ' of ' + this.totalSlides;
 },

